How can I ensure proper conversion of messages in my Flutter chat app?
I'm encountering a problem in my Flutter (Dart) code for a chat group I'm building. The issue arises in the chat screen where, upon testing, all messages appear on the right side, even when sent by different users. How can I ensure proper alignment of messages in my Flutter chat app, where messages sent by different users appear on the correct side of the screen, and include relevant user information such as sender name and timestamp? I've included the relevant code snippets below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:emoji_picker_flutter/emoji_picker_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';



String formatTime(DateTime time) {
  return DateFormat('HH:mm').format(time);
}

class Message {
  final String id;
  final String content;
  final String senderId;
  final String senderName;
  final DateTime timestamp;
  final String appogee;
  final String cne;

  Message({
    required this.id,
    required this.content,
    required this.senderId,
    required this.senderName,
    required this.timestamp,
    required this.appogee,
    required this.cne,
  });
}




class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final Message message;
  final bool isSentByCurrentUser;
  final VoidCallback onDeletePressed;
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId;
  // ignore: annotate_overrides, overridden_fields
  final Key? key; // Add Key parameter

  const MessageBubble({
    this.key, // Pass Key parameter to superclass constructor
    required this.message,
    required this.isSentByCurrentUser,
    required this.onDeletePressed,
    required this.chatGroupId,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () => _showMessageOptions(context, message, isSentByCurrentUser, chatGroupId),
      child: Align(
        alignment: isSentByCurrentUser ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight, // Swap alignment condition
        child: _messageBubble(message, context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _messageBubble(Message message, BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: isSentByCurrentUser ? MainAxisAlignment.start : MainAxisAlignment.end, // Adjust MainAxisAlignment based on isSentByCurrentUser
      children: [
        if (!isSentByCurrentUser) ...[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              message.senderName,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Colors.grey[600],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(message.content.contains('https://') ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .03 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .04),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .04, vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .01),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isSentByCurrentUser ?  Colors.blueGrey : const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 43, 48),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(isSentByCurrentUser ? 0 : 30),
                topRight: Radius.circular(isSentByCurrentUser ? 30 : 0),
                bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(30),
              ),
            ),
            child: !message.content.contains('https://')
                ? Text(
                    message.content,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: isSentByCurrentUser ? Colors.black : Colors.white),
                  )
                : ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    child: Image.network(
                      message.content,
                      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                        return Icon(Icons.image, size: 70, color: isSentByCurrentUser ? Colors.black87 : Colors.white);
                      },
                      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes! : null,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


  // Add _showMessageOptions method here
  void _showMessageOptions(BuildContext context, Message message, bool isSentByCurrentUser, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Message Options'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Content: ${message.content}'),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              Text('Sender: ${message.senderName}'),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              Text('Timestamp: ${message.timestamp}'),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            if (isSentByCurrentUser)
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  _showMessageUpdateDialog(context, message, isSentByCurrentUser, chatGroupId);
                },
                child: const Text('Update'),
              ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                _deleteMessage(message.id, chatGroupId); // Call the delete callback
              },
              child: const Text('Delete'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // Add _showMessageUpdateDialog method here
  void _showMessageUpdateDialog(BuildContext context, Message message, bool isSentByCurrentUser, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId) {
    String updatedMsg = message.content;

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.message,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 28,
            ),
            Text(' Update Message')
          ],
        ),
        content: TextFormField(
          initialValue: updatedMsg,
          maxLines: null,
          onChanged: (value) => updatedMsg = value,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Cancel',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              _updateMessage(updatedMsg, message.id, chatGroupId);
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Update',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

void _updateMessage(String updatedMsg, String messageId, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('EST-groupes')
    .doc(chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? chatGroupId[0].id : null)
    .collection('messages')
    .doc(messageId)
    .update({
      'content': updatedMsg,
    }).then((_) {
      // Update successful
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Message updated successfully');
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      // Handle errors
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Failed to update message: $error');
      }
    });
}

// In _deleteMessage and _updateMessage methods
void _deleteMessage(String messageId, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('EST-groupes')
    .doc(chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? chatGroupId[0].id : null)
    .collection('messages')
    .doc(messageId)
    .delete()
    .then((_) {
      // Deletion successful
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Message deleted successfully');
      }
    })
    .catchError((error) {
      // Handle errors
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Failed to delete message: $error');
      }
    });
}



}



class CommunicationGroupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String cne;
  final String appogee;
  final String filiere;
  final int anneeScolaire;
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId;
  final String senderName; // Add senderName parameter

  const CommunicationGroupPage({
    required this.cne,
    required this.appogee,
    required this.filiere,
    required this.anneeScolaire,
    required this.chatGroupId,
    required this.senderName, // Include senderName parameter
    super.key, // Add key parameter
  }); // Call super constructor with key parameter

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _CommunicationGroupPageState createState() => _CommunicationGroupPageState();
}



class _CommunicationGroupPageState extends State<CommunicationGroupPage> {
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isSendingMessage = false;
  late FlutterSoundRecorder _audioRecorder;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _audioRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Communication Group'),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 152, 0),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'lib/images/pattdark.png',
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: _buildChatInterface(context),
              ),
              _buildChatInput(context),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  
Widget _buildChatInterface(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: _getChatMessagesStream(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
        return const Center(child: Text('Say Hi! '));
      }

final List<Message> messages = snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
  final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return Message(
    id: doc.id,
    content: data['content'] ?? '', // Changed 'content' to 'text'
    senderId: data['sender'] ?? '',
    senderName: data['senderName'] ?? '', // Using senderName from data
    timestamp: (data['timestamp'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
    appogee: data['appogee'] ?? '', // Added 'appogee'
    cne: data['cne'] ?? '', // Added 'cne'
  );
}).toList();


      messages.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp.compareTo(b.timestamp)); // Sort messages by timestamp
      return ListView.builder(
        reverse: false, // Show new messages at the bottom
        itemCount: messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final message = messages[index];
    final isSentByCurrentUser = message.senderId == widget.cne; // Assuming widget.cne holds the current user's ID
          return MessageBubble(
            message: message,
            isSentByCurrentUser: isSentByCurrentUser,
            onDeletePressed: () => _deleteMessage(message.id),
            chatGroupId: widget.chatGroupId,
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
}


  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _getChatMessagesStream() {
    if (widget.chatGroupId.isEmpty) {
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('EST-groupes').doc().collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
    } else {
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('EST-groupes').doc(widget.chatGroupId[0].id).collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
    }
  }







  Widget _buildChatInput(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    color: Colors.grey[200],
    child: Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => EmojiPicker(
                onEmojiSelected: (category, emoji) {
                  _messageController.text += emoji.emoji;
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (_) {
              _startRecordingVoiceMessage();
            },
            onTapUp: (_) {
              _stopRecordingVoiceMessage();
            },
            onTapCancel: () {
              _stopRecordingVoiceMessage();
            },
            child: TextField(
              controller: _messageController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Type your message...',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _isSendingMessage = true;
                });
              },
              onChanged: (text) {
                setState(() {
                  _isSendingMessage = text.isNotEmpty;
                });
              },
              onSubmitted: (_) {
                if (_isSendingMessage) {
                  _sendMessage(context);
                } else {
                  _startRecordingVoiceMessage();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
            if (result != null) {
              PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
              // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
              _sendFileMessage(context, file);
            }
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.attach_file),
        ),
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    _sendMessage(context);
    _messageController.clear(); // Clear the message

  },
  icon: _isSendingMessage ? const Icon(Icons.send) : const Icon(Icons.mic),
),


      ],
    ),
  );
}

void _startRecordingVoiceMessage() async {
    try {
      await _audioRecorder.openRecorder();
      await _audioRecorder.startRecorder(toFile: 'path_to_save_recording');
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Recording started.');
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Error starting recording: $e');
    }
  }
  void _stopRecordingVoiceMessage() async {
    try {
      await _audioRecorder.stopRecorder();
      await _audioRecorder.closeRecorder();
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Recording stopped.');

      // Now you can handle the recorded audio file (e.g., send it in a chat message)
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Error stopping recording: $e');
    }
  }




  void _sendFileMessage(BuildContext context, PlatformFile file) {
String senderName = widget.senderName;

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('File selected: ${file.name}');
    }
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('EST-groupes')
        .doc(widget.chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? widget.chatGroupId[0].id : null)
        .collection('messages')
        .add({
      'content': 'File selected: ${file.name}',
      'sender': senderName,
      'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
    });
  }

  // ignore: unused_element
  void _sendVoiceMessage() {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('Voice message sent');
  }

  Future<void> _sendMessage(BuildContext context) async {
    String messageText = _messageController.text.trim();
    if (messageText.isNotEmpty) {
String senderName = widget.senderName;
      try {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('EST-groupes')
            .doc(widget.chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? widget.chatGroupId[0].id : null)
            .collection('messages')
            .add({
          'content': messageText,
          'sender': senderName,
          'senderName': senderName, // Add senderName field
          'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
        });
        _messageController.clear(); // Clear the message
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle error
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Failed to send message: $e');
        }
      }
    }
  }


 Future<void> _deleteMessage(String messageId) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('EST-groupes')
          .doc(widget.chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? widget.chatGroupId[0].id : null)
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(messageId)
          .delete();
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Failed to delete message: $e');
      }
    }
  }
}

[in the image you see that two uses how there messages are]](https://i.sstatic.net/TMnZC1LJ.jpg)

    required this.cne,
    required this.appogee,
    required this.filiere,
    required this.anneeScolaire,
    required this.chatGroupId,
    required this.senderName, // Include senderName parameter
    super.key, // Add key parameter
  });```

We need to see how this constructor is called. The constructor calls and it's parameters decide how messages will be aligned.

have you tried to pass either true or false for the isSentByCurrentUser of MessageBubble while keeping everything else to check if the bubbles change sides?
If they do the problem is not in the UI code but how you get to the value that you pass to isSentByCurrentUser
